# jQuery: select children as hidden input type?

Tags: jquery, selector, hidden-field

inside of my div.hanging is a form. This form contains a hidden inputfield with a class `.hiddenField`

Like this:

```
<form>
    <input class="input1 hiddenField" name="user[current_password]" type="hidden">
</form>
```

My jQuery…

```
$('.hanging form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('.hiddenField').val('test');
        triggerAjaxSubmit(formId, true);
    });
```

Any idea why this selector won't work? I simply need to select the hidden field inside of the form depending on `$(this)`.

Comment: What about it is not working?

Comment: how do you know the selector does not work ?

Comment: yes it is an immediate descendant!

Comment: @Gaby It doesn't do it's job. moreove I do that `console.log($(this).children('.hiddenField').val());`

Comment: @mathiregister, judging by the answer you selected, the `input` element is **not** an immediate child of the form as @mu was suggesting.. check the example that works http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/U4b7A/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.hanging form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.hiddenField').val('test');
    triggerAjaxSubmit(formId, true);
});
```

> I simply need to select the hidden field inside of the form depending
>   on $(this).

```
$(this).find('.hiddenField');
```

Comment: @mathiregister, If this is the correct answer, then the `input` is **not** and immediate child of the form..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
  $(this).find('.hiddenField').val('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find`

```
$('.hanging form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find(".hiddenField").val('test');
        triggerAjaxSubmit(formId, true);
    });
```

[`jquery find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)